# Graph marking with lives

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

You're given an non directed graph with integer node weights and edge weights.

A node is "mark-able" if its node weight is non negative, and marking a node will cause all its neighbors node weights to decrease by the edge weight of the edge connecting the two. 
If a marked node's node weight goes below 0, it's automatically unmarked (and the decrease of its neighbors edge weights is also undone).

Solve for a largest possible set of marked nodes.

Potentially easier problems:

- Limit the edge weights to be positive.
- Limit the edge weights to all be 1.
- Solve for the size of the solution set instead of the set itself.

Is this problem solvable in polynomial time? What's the best solution?

Comment: 1. Sounds like a weighted matching in a non-bipartite graph. May be solvable by finding minimum cost maximum flow, the question then is, given the graph, find the right network for the flow. 2. The question altogether may be better suited for cs.stackexchange.com. 3. Sadly, the question does not show much research effort, though it does list easier questions to answer first, which is a good first step.

Comment: @Gassa Thanks for the feedback. I have tried some research, but I've not made much progress, mostly due to not knowing where to start.

Comment: With a bit more thought, I *think* (not sure, hoping it will be peer reviewed) the problem includes finding minimum vertex cover as a special case. Posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this sounds like a generalization of the [minimum vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem, which is known to be NP-complete.

Indeed, consider a graph where weights of vertices are 0 and weights of edges are 1.
For each edge, we can mark at most one of its endpoints: otherwise, both their weights will become negative.
This property also goes backwards, meaning that any set of markings that follows the "single marked endpoint" property is also a solution. 
This means that we want to mark the largest possible set of vertices so that each edge is connected to at most one marked vertex.
In turn, this means that we want to find the smallest possible set of *unmarked* vertices so that each edge is connected to at least one *unmarked* vertex.
Considering there are no isolated vertices, it sounds like the *unmarked* vertices are the minimum vertex cover.

Comment: Actually, this is also the independent set problem for vertices weighted 0 and edges weighted 1.